# Why doesn't the jQuery background animation work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner web designer, and though I would try my hand at JavaScript and jQuery. After looking around [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) for a bit, I tried to make a simple jQuery animation, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#name").blur(funtion(){
                    if(value==null || value==""){
                        $("#name").animate({background:#D23E42}, "slow");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        #name
        {
            background:#6BAA64;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border:2px none;
            padding:5px;
            -webkit-border-radius:8px 8px;
            -moz-border-radius:8px 8px;
            border-radius:8px 8px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="text-align: center;">
        Name:
        <br />
        <input id="name" type="text" value="Your Name" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I was just trying to setup a simple contact/registration form model, so when the name field was left empty, or wasn't changed, would turn red (on blur).

Comment: I don't think you can animate background.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code, also I dont think you can animate background colours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got **many** mistakes in that code:

```
$("#name").blur(function() {
    if (!this.value) {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#D23E42');
    }
});​
```

**Mistakes:**

- `funtion` => `function`
- `value` => `this.value`.
- The value of an input can never be `null`, it can be only an empty string.
- `animate` => `css`, and the reason is that you can't animate background-color changes without a plugin.
- the color needs to be a string `#D23E42` => `'#D23E42'`
- `background` => `background-color`.
- `$("#name")` => `$(this)`

It might be a good idea to stop learning at w3school as it doesn't seem to pay off...

Comment: **downvote reason???** @downvoter, if you don't know why you're voting,  just don't vote!

Comment: `Some men just want to watch the world burn`, good answer though, +1 :D

Comment: great answer. have an upvote from me to get that downvote back.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but you can't animate background, unless you use [jColor](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated **but background-color cannot be**, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.animate` cannot animate background colours, but only properties like `width, height, left, top` etc. To animate background colours, you'll have to use a plugin like https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes:

1. The color value is a string, so you need quotes around "#D23E42". Otherwise you're probably seeing a syntax error.
2. JQuery doesn't actually animate colors anyway. There's a plugin that claims to add this feature though I haven't tried it out:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: he got more than just two. read my answer, he has even syntax errors.

Comment: So he did, my response was after a quick glance at the animate code itself. Maybe we should point him at a JavaScript console so he can see where his syntax errors are.

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ixofuv/3/edit)*

```
$("#name").focusout(function(){                  
  var value = $.trim($(this).val());                 
  if(value === ''){    
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#D23E42'}, 500);
  }   
});
```

- In this demo I used the jQuery UI library to achieve the background fade color.
- Use [.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)
- Use [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to prevent empty spaces being accepted as valid input
- Always use `===` to compare values

**EDIT**
Hede is a demo without the UI
You surely need to redo the color if the user reenter some text:

```
$("#name").focusout(function(){                
  var value = $.trim($(this).val());                 
  if(value === ''){    
    $(this).css({background:'#D23E42'});
  }else{
    $(this).css({background:'#6BAA64'});
  }
});
```

### *[Demo without the UI library](http://jsbin.com/ixofuv/4/edit)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the speedy responses everyone!

Comment: @Nyanja I reedited my answer. Added `$.trim()`  to prevent empty spaces being accepted. Thanks to you.